# Distance from a vector to a linear span vectors in a separable Hilbert space.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, infinite-matrices

Consider a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Let $F$ be a vector subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ and let $v\in\mathcal{H}$. If $F$ is of finite dimension $n$, then the distance from $v$ to $F$ can be expressed as $$d(v,F)=\sqrt{\frac{G(v,f_1,...,f_n)}{G(f_1,...,f_n)}},$$ where $(f_1,...,f_n)$ is any basis of $F$ and where for all $k\ge1$ and all $x_1,...,x_k\in\mathcal{H}$, $G(x_1,...,x_k)$ is the determinant of the Gram matrix $(<x_i|x_j>)_{1\le i,j\le k}$.

1. The above formula doesn't depend on the choice of basis. Is there a convenient "symmetrized" formula that is not expressed as a function of a particular basis but rather depending on all the elements of $F$ in a symmetric fashion?
2. Is there an analog formula if the dimension of $F$ is infinite?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are infinitely many vectors in the subspace. What would a "symmetric formula" look like other than an expression with $\min$? Something with integrals?

Comment: Yes I was thinking of a formula with integrals.

Comment: For the finite dimensional case, you might start with what you think should be done in one dimension.  For the infinite dimensional case, it seems the best you could hope for as a "formula" is to take a limit of finite dimensional subspaces $F$.  There seems to be no practical way to detect when $v$ belongs to (or is arbitrarily close to) some subspace without producing a basis.